# how to inflate another xml layout inside scrollview

Tags: android, xml

```
****Main.xml****
```

this my main.xml layout and i want inflate another layout inside scrollview's linear layout. so please someone suggest me how to inflate another layout inside the scrollview.

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/productDetailsLayout"

        >
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/productDetailsLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

                >
                <TextView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

                </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/productDetailsLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

                >          
      <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                >
         <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/productDetailsLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

                >


                </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

please look another layout dynamic_lyaout.xml.

when i inflate the xml then exception occur. so please someone help

dynamic_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/abc"
               >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"

                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textColor="#CC0033"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"

                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"

                    android:text="Price:"
                    android:textColor="#Cd0023"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="#3399FF"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
                     <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="#880808" 
                        android:layout_below="@+id/desc"/>        

            </RelativeLayout>
```

please my code below

```
 LinearLayout mainlayou = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.productDetailsLayout);
     ScrollView scview=(ScrollView)mainlayou.findViewById(R.id.scview);
     LinearLayout scviewLayout1 = (LinearLayout)scview.findViewById(R.id.productDetailsLayout1);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
     LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
     scviewLayout1.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_layout,
             mainlayou, false));
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?? you are doing right

Comment: Read this link and try it...,[http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: first set unique id of your all linearlayout and then try my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code:

inflator_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llDIsplayForToDoInflater"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/aliceblue"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtdt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:textSize="20sp" >
                </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java File:

```
LinearLayout llDisplayData, llChangeBG;
TextView tvtxt;

llDisplayData = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.productDetailsLayout1);
LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View customView;

llDisplayData.removeAllViews();

customView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.inflator_layout, null);

llChangeBG = (LinearLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.llDIsplayForToDoInflater);

tvtxt = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtdt);
llDisplayData.addView(customView);
```

Comment: i want to inflate inside scrollview actually? please see the my xml code.

Comment: @Pramod i know. i used linearlayout of scrollview.. just see my code. and implement it. after that if you face any problem then let me know.

Comment: i implement your code in work but one problem all layout display horizontally not vertically..please give the suggesion

Comment: You have to set android:orientation="vertical" on your LinearLayout which is inside ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add this code in you scroll view you will get your include layout.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/productDetailsLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           >
   <include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/your_layour" />
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: my dear i want to inflate by coding? please see the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_layout, productDetailsLayout1, false);
                    //content.addView(v);
                    LinearLayout scrolloyouts=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.productDetailsLayout1);

                    LinearLayout loginlayout=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.abc);
                    scrolloyouts.removeAllViews();
                    scrolloyouts.addView(abc);
```